# BX Slider forwarding to last slide (when it's not supposed to)

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I wondered if any one could shed some light into this BXSlider issue:

http://codepen.io/richerimage/live/47705eb80c7d86870e21acfd4a1ac39a

When trying to navigate though the slides (right-hand column) it will only stay on the first (#s 1,2,3) and last (#s 7,8,9) group of slides.

Whenever you try to navigate to the middle set (#s 4,5,6) it only 'sticks' for a split second before forwarding you to the last set of slides.

Any ideas why and how to fix?

Grateful thanks in advance :)

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Looks like bxSlider doesn't support jQuery 1.11.0 just yet. Try downgrading to 1.10.2, it worked for me. :)